# JSF error page message

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jsf-2, error-handling

I have a project, written on JSF. Now I need to display an error message on my error page. At the moment I display them like this:

```
<h:outputText id="errormsg" value="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}"/>
```

and get not only the error message, but also an error class itself, like this:

> com.bar.foo.IncorrectPasswordException: "Incorrect password!"

How can I display only the error message itself?
Thanks

Comment: By the way, providing information that an exact part of provided credentials was incorrect is considered a bad practice. Better print "login/password is incorrect".

Comment: This is my mentor's will, not my own. Still, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<h:messages>`, as it is the default message handler for JSF. Look at this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-message-and-messages-example/). Then you can use the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) for adding messages to FacesContext:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
  .addMessage(new FacesMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, yourMessage));
```

And you'll get them printed by the `<h:messages>` tag.